# Couponcode for one free product

Tags: coupon-codes

Is it possible to generate a couponcode which do the following

- Only one product for free
- No shipping costs
- Valid for one person only (i.e. winner)

If this is possible can somebody explain me how to achieve this?

Comment: means are you telling you want to give 100 % discount for only one particular product or any one product that user added to cart.

Comment: Yes and also free shipping

Comment: what shipping method you are using ?

Comment: `Valid for one person` means one customer can use only once ? or it should applicable only to particular customer ?

Comment: We've about 1500 buyers and just one on of all these buyers can use this coupon

Comment: okay, i assume than all buyers can use the coupon code only once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i apply coupon code if order total value is greater than 100 INR?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147442/how-can-i-apply-coupon-code-if-order-total-value-is-greater-than-100-inr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not tested solution, first you check in demo site, if it works than implement in live site**

Go to `Promotions > Shopping cart Price rules > click on Add new Rule` , than enter the information

and give value as " `Uses per Customer : 1` " => allow only once per customer

under Actions , follow as below image :

[image]

Enter the sku that you want to give free under "sku textfield".

let me know if you face any problems.

you can get more information here :

http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/08/how-to-create-coupon-codes-in-magento-beginners-tutorial-1/

https://stuntcoders.com/magento-tutorials/prices-and-promotion/creating-coupon-code/

Comment: Although maybe usefull in the furure this is not what I meant. Sorry, English is not my native language. I mean we give just one product away so it's one product for just one our 1500 clients instead of 1 free product for each clienmt

Comment: are you telling you want to give discount only for one buyer , in that case you can send coupon code only to that buyer.

Comment: Okay it's partly working because it only discounted without the VAT. i.e. 59 euro is 48 euro discount but leeves 10 euro (21% VAT). How can I discount including VAT

Comment: @Peter Look under `System > Configuration > Tax`

Under **Calculation Settings**, you can see `Apply Discount on Prices` ,  change value there and check.