# How can i apply coupon code if order total value is greater than 100 INR?

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon, coupon-codes

How to create and apply coupon codes for total order value is greater than 100 INR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to Promotions > Shopping cart price rules > than create new rules with below condition :

Steps : **General information**

[image]

[image]

**step 2** : conditions

[image]

**step 3** : Actions

[image]

Apply "100" as coupon code in shopping cart page. also enter the discount amount under "Actions"

chek these [link1](http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/shopping-cart-price-rules) & [link2](http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/shopping-cart-price-rules-in-magento-walk-through/) for more information

Comment: i did that, when i apply its not working

Comment: pls join chat..

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49079/http-magento-stackexchange-com-questions-147442-how-can-i-apply-coupon-code-if

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara   could u pls join chat

Comment: @JeevaRathinam please check update and follow it....

Comment: @ baby :how can i give condition greater than 100

Comment: please click on conditions tab present in left side and than you can see "+" symbol ,  just click on that, than you select as i did in attached image. @JeevaRathinam

Comment: also you can [youtube videos](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Z943WMHvNoXT8gfY05y4Cg&gws_rd=ssl#q=magento+create+shopping+cart+price+rule+you+tube) here better explaination..... @JeevaRathinam

Comment: @ baby : there is only subtotal, total item qty, weight, no what you mentioned like greatet than.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/voqjq3c.png

Comment: you can click on `subtotal` & than click on `is`, than you can get option to select `subtotal is greater than`..... @JeevaRathinam

Comment: Okay @ baby....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49081/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-baby-in-magento).

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Promotions->Shopping Cart Price Rules** create new rule with coupon code

Go to condition tab add condition as in below image:

[image]

Go to **Actions** select Apply as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

Login to Admin panel > Promotions > Shopping cart price rules > than create new rules with below condition :

Steps : **General information**
[image]

**step 2** : conditions 
[image]

**step 3** : Actions
[image]

Apply "your coupon code" as coupon code in shopping cart page. also enter the discount amount under "Actions"

Please remove cache. I hope it will help you